# Is there a way/library to de/serialize Dynamodb dump file data?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

my objective is to read from a Dynamodb dump file, for each line deserialize the line into POJO, modify it, serialize it to string then write that string to a file; last step would be to import the data back into Dynamodb using the file i written the modified strings.

imagine i have a dynamodb dump file with the following:

```
nameETX{"s":"batman"}STXtimestampETX{"s":"2015-03-04"}STXstatusETX{"s":"APPROVED"}
nameETX{"s":"batman"}STXtimestampETX{"s":"2015-03-04"}STXstatusETX{"s":"APPROVED"}
nameETX{"s":"batman"}STXtimestampETX{"s":"2015-03-04"}STXstatusETX{"s":"APPROVED"}
nameETX{"s":"batman"}STXtimestampETX{"s":"2015-03-04"}STXstatusETX{"s":"APPROVED"}
```

is there a library or factory method which i can use to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds like the goal is to do bulk editing of data in DynamoDB. Would it be possible to do a scan of the data, modify each item as you page through the results, then write the item back as you finish processing each page? Bulk writing to DynamoDB all at once might cause throttling so updating each item individually over time may be better for this reason as well.

Comment: @JohnnyWu right, the idea is just read the dump file, modify data, write to a separate dump file to be imported to dynamo. r/w the dump files is easier since i wouldnt have to reload the data if somehow the program messes up somewhere. currently im looking at just parsing out the special chars via regex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

**deserialize by the STX then ETX, save the values to a map**

**serialize by creating string following the dynamo db format**

- **`STXfield_nameETX{"field_type":"value"}`**

Unfortunately, I've not found any library that can automatically do this.

I wrote my own de/serializer to accomplish this.

Since each variable has the STX/ETX delimiters:

- I split each line by the STX

  - This will give me: `[nameETX{"s":"batman"},timestampETX{"s":"2015-03-04"},statusETX{"s":"APPROVED"}]`
- From that, I split once again by ETX

  - This will give me: `["name", "{"s":"batman"}"]`
- For each field, I saved that into a Map; the value should be parsed out of the json string.

For serialization, it's simpler, just join the field name with STX and ETX then append the value as a json string.